# .htaccess domain directory does not resolve domain.com/domain properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 domains that point to the same IP `foo.com` and `bar.com`

I don't have access to setting up a virtual host for the domains but I have managed to create `.htaccess` rules so that it is setup like this.

- foo.com points to / directory
- bar.com points to /bar directory

Having the setup above now I could have different `index.html` files for accessing the root of the domain.

This is the rule I implemented for `bar.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bar/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar/$1 [L]
```

The above rule works perfectly however when I navigate to `bar.com/bar` it doesn't give me a `404` but instead it still points to the root of my `bar` directory.

So, I created another `RewriteCond` to handle such issue.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "(GET|POST) \/bar\/ HTTP/"
```

While the `RewriteCond` works perfectly. I am not sure what rewrite rule I would write so that when the user visits `bar.com/bar` it would point to the `/bar/bar` directory and thus would give me a `404`

I tried the `RewriteRule` below but it doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ bar/bar/$1  [L,QSA]
```

So I temporarily created a redirect to the main `bar.com` domain.

```
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ http://bar.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks @anubhava

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "(GET|POST) \/bar\/(.*) HTTP/"
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+bar[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^bar(/.*|)$ /bar/bar$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Using your rules above. It is similar to what I have created. Whenever I access ``bar.com/bar`` I get redirected to ``bar.com`` what I would want to do is for this to return a `404` error because `/bar/bar` folder does not exist on the server

Comment: Hi, thanks. Sure it redirects to 404 however. what if I really had a ``/bar/bar`` folder it should then give me something under that folder. So basically what I wanted was.. ``bar.com -> /bar`` and ``bar.com/bar -> /bar/bar`` without showing in the url.

Comment: Hi Thanks, it works.. however not for request like this ``bar.com/bar/file.html`` it should point to ``/bar/bar/file.html``

Comment: Is `/bar/file.html` an actual file or `/bar/bar/file.html` is actual file?

Comment: ``/bar/bar/file.html`` is the actual file and should be accessed using ``bar.com/bar/file.html`` I got it now with a minor edit on your answer so I may accept this now as an answer.